# How to Return html content to view?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

So i have a problem in which i had to redirect to a url with headers. However , powers beyond my control taught that when one redirects the headers are lost . The only way to do it is to make the ui create that request with the headers . 
However after a bit of googling i found out that if i create a get request at backend i can include the headers and it will return the entire html page which can be converted into response string . 
So the question would be that is it possible to take that html content , wrap it in a view and then send it back ?

My code looks like this and it is working :

```
@GetMapping(value="/")
    public RedirectView home(Model model) {


    URL url;
    try {
        Credentials cred=new Credentials();
        url = new URL(cred.getLinkedInUrl()+"?"+"client_id="+cred.getAppid()
        +"&grant_type=client_credentials&response_type=code&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress&redirect_uri="+cred.getRedirect_uri());
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "it-it");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

          String inputLine;
          while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(inputLine);
          }
          br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    model.addAttribute("credentials", new Credentials());

    return new RedirectView("someurl");
}
```

Comment: Just as you said you cannot pass headers with a redirect request.

Checking your code, it seems that you want to implement an OAuth login/signup client credential grant type flow.

Why not return the parameters to the client-side handle the call to LinkedIn in this case since its supposed to load a LinkedIn login screen?